# Excepción de instanciamiento al ejecutar oReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(urlJasper);

Tags: java

La excepción salta al ejecutarse esta línea:

```
oReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(urlJasper);
```

> cannot assign instance of
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField to field
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of
> type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph

¿Cómo se podría solucionar? ¿A que se debe este tipo de error?

Comment: ¿La excepción no da más información de porqué no se puede asignar? En principio el Javadoc indica que JRBaseTextField implement JRParagraphContainer, así que la asignación debería ser legal. En todo caso, revisa como hacer un [mcve] (incluyendo el código .jrxml) e indica la versión de JasperReports

Comment: La versión es TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.3.1 final. No puedo poner el código aquí porque sobrepasa con creces los caracteres.